# php upload without leaving page

Tags: php, ajax, json, file, upload

Just wondered if anyone could help with this one please :

Let's say i have a form as follows :

```
<form name="mymainform" method="post" action="step2code.php"> 

  Enter Description : <input type="text" value="" name="description" />

  Enter File URL (or press upload): <input type="text" value="" name="fileurl" />

  <input type="button" name="uploadbutton" onclick="DO_CODE_HERE" />

  <input type="submit" name="func" value="Next Step" /> 

</form>
```

Basically,  just a form that allows you to input a description and a file (image) URL - When you click the "Next Step" button it will pass the description text (description) and the URL (fileurl) to the next program it calls (step2code.php) - This will work just fine if the user enters a description and MANUALLY enters a URL - It will go on to run step2code.php and process the data.

However,  what I would LIKE it to do is,  if someone presses the button called "uploadbutton",  it allows you to choose a file from your computer and then uploads it to a predetermined directory (which will already be set in a variable) - However,  After the file has uploaded I don't want the form to refresh (there is lots of other data not shown here) - I just want it to (if successfull) return the URL of the uploaded file and place it in the field "fileurl".

Any ideas on the easiest way to do it please?

Comment: You cannnot upload a file with ajax. You need to either use an iframe (so it doesnt look like the page refreshes) or flash / silverlight. Doing the following will allow the user to select the file on their computer. <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /> you also need to specify the form as enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: -1. This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: maybe they are a new developer? I hope so atleast.

Comment: @james31rock: Being new is not an excuse for not researching.

Comment: @Truth, you are correct on that. -1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for the support guys :)  I DID research it but found some quite convulted solutions using ajax and jquery and also some using other 3rd party plugins such as uploadify.  They all seemed to complex for what I wanted to do!  @james31rock,  yes I am a new developer to PHP/Javascript,  I have come from a VB & C# background and now have to develop web tech to run on standard LAMP servers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `<input type="file">`? <sub>Probably not</sub>

Also, you will need to use an iframe or some similar techniques, in order to upload without refreshing the page.

Comment: Or AJAX it with Jquerify in order to upload the Public Static Asynchronously!

Comment: <input type="file"> would work as I don't actually need to upload it at this stage BUT I would PREFER to upload it at this stage so that I can trap errors such as a wrong filetype or a user hitting the php.ini upload size limits

Comment: Actually - looking at this,  if I did use <input type="file">,  I could then process it on the next page.  How would I do that though?  Would I just set the $_FILES["file"] variable to be equal to the field value of the local URL?

Answer (score 0):

make function which uploads the file and let submit button redirect you to same page, keep a check on some variables if set (isset in php), upload was successful.
You can use those variables for saving the link of file uploaded.

Comment: I was thinking of something along the same lines:  let's say my form is in a file called main.php - I could call the "uploader" program with all the variables stored in a session and then call the "calling" program again and pass the vars back in the session but have a handler at the beginning that checks where it has come from and fills in the fields - sounds like there should be a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 0):

As others (including myself in the comment) have said, You cannot upload a file asynchronously. You need to either use an iframe or flash/ silverlight.

```
<form name="mymainform" method="post" action="step2code.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 

  Enter Description : <input type="text" value="" name="description" />

  Enter File URL (or press upload): <input type="file" name="fileurl" />

  <input type="button" name="uploadbutton" onclick="DO_CODE_HERE" />

  <input type="submit" name="func" value="Next Step" /> 

</form>
```

If you use an iframe it will look like the page did not refresh.

Comment: Thanks James - But how do I pass the URL back from the iFrame into the form text field value (I am guessing on using some Javascript in the iFrame to fill in the value) ?